# Как задать стили тегу code, не находящегося внутри тега pre?

Tags: css

На странице есть отдельные теги `code`, а есть теги `code`, находящиеся внутри тега `pre`. Как задать стили для тега `code`, чтобы они работали только для отдельного тега, не находящегося внутри тега `pre`?

Нужно, чтобы стили работали только для `<code>code text</code>`

Делаю это так, но не уверен, что это правильно:

```css
*:not(pre)>code {
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: #e9eaec;
  font-size: 14px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<pre>
    <code>
      Object object = getMyList();
      List&lt;Integer&gt; list = (List&lt;Integer&gt;) object;
    </code>
</pre>
<code>code text</code>
```

Comment: `pre > code {}`

Comment: Это стили для тега <code> внутри <pre>. А нужно задать стили для <code> не входящего в <pre>. А тот, что дочерний, для него стили на задавать.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127580/discussion-between-yar85-and-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильным вариантом будет добавление класса:

```css
code.inline {
  padding: 2px 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 14px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-break: break-all;
  background: #e9eaec;
}
```

```html
<pre>
  <code>
      Object object = getMyList();
      List&lt;Integer&gt; list = (List&lt;Integer&gt;) object;
  </code>
</pre>

<code class="inline">code text</code>
```

Но, раз хочется "дёшево и сердито", то так:

```css
code {
  padding: 2px 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 14px;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  word-break: break-all;
  background: #e9eaec;
}

pre code { all: unset; }
```

```html
<pre>
  <code>
      Object object = getMyList();
      List&lt;Integer&gt; list = (List&lt;Integer&gt;) object;
  </code>
</pre>

<code class="inline">code text</code>
```